# Is it possible to share a view of some html node as an image to Facebook/Twitter with pure javascript?

Tags: facebook, html, social-networking

For example, I have a div with some content (can be anything like table, images and even canvas) inside. I want to share that as an image to social networks like Facebook/Twitter. Is it possible to do that without saving a picture to local or on remote server but directly at the users' side?

Thanks,

Comment: No.. none of Facebook, Twitter or any other site can read something was appended to the `<body>` of a page, OG meta must be added via server-side

Comment: @AdamAzad Then is it possible to change dynamically? For example, when the user clicks button a let's share img 1 and when the user clicks button b let's share img 2. Thanks

Comment: Neither that would work, unless each share button shares a different URL which has different OG meta tags (title (could be the same), the image, description etc..) for example, the first button will share http://example.com/url-1 while the 2nd shares http://example.com/url-2

Comment: @AdamAzad Thanks, so if not the images, what about the text for Facebook? If I just want to change the title/description, is that possible?